# jaspersoft creating custom data adapter for jdbc connection

Tags: jdbc, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I'm using japsersoft studio, I want to create my own custom data adapter for jdbc connection, so that connection details will be stored in file or class or package we can say.... and using this file I"m going to connect with data source in jaspersoft.
I have searched on internet but found nothing. 
So if there is any way to create our own custom adapter for jdbc connection in jaspsersoft studio it will very helpful.

Or any way through which I can store jdbc(data source) credentials in file and can use that file for accessing database connection in jasper studio. so if i modify details in file then database source should also be modified in jaspersoft.

Thank you.

Comment: What is a reason to create such adapter (with custom method of storing connection details)? How are you planning to use it? Do you have some code for using template?

Comment: We want to modify connection through other application. so we want to store connection details in file which will be used by jaspersoft.

Comment: You don't need data adapter in Studio for building report from code

Comment: Alex you misunderstood, I want to connect to database using data adapter but I want my own custom data adapter based on details on this adapter connection will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in exporting your DataAdapter defined in JSS to an XML file and reference that one instead. More info here: [Importing and Exporting Data Sources](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/importing-and-exporting-data-sources).

Be warned, that if you want to share the adapter file you will be, most likely, saving the credentials in clear text which is totally unsafe. A more secure way would be to enable the [Secure Storage](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/eclipse-secure-storage-jaspersoft-studio) for credentials. This way, instead of the password, your file will contain the encrypted password.

If you export and save the adapter file inside your JSS project you can pick it from the DataAdapter drop-down when previewing the report.